# navmesh agent and obstacle on the same gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, navmesh

i am trying to add navmesh obstacle and navmesh agent component on the same GameObject. However, I am getting a strange behaviour (the object will keep change it position randomly).

SO, if we have two agents in a narrow corridor, although they block each other path as in the figure, both agents will still have a path. Both agents will run to each other and push each other because there is no space to execute RVO (an algorithm that unity use to avoid obstacles) and navmesh will not re-plan a new path.
[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ4qS.png)

can anyone help!

thank you in advance

MD

Comment: Please provide better explanation of what outcome do you expect, and the code you tried

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Navmesh agents already avoid other navmesh agents (based on their radius setting).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the navmesh obstacle to a child of the navmesh agent

Comment: No, it doesn't work because the agent will try to avoid itself. There is a solution but it is expensive and i do not really want to use it which is baking navmesh at runtime with adding navmesh volumes to the agents.

Comment: I googled it and found out u don't need a navmash object, navmash agents can avoid each other by the radius setting. [Navmash avoidance](https://forum.unity.com/threads/navmeshagent-being-nav-mesh-obstacle-at-the-same-time.602128/)

Comment: Bro it will not solve the case i have please read the question and look at the figure attached